# "Argument list too long" when try to open 10.025 pdfs

Tags: bash, pdf

I'm using the node module `Pdf-text-extract` to extract pdfs texts, and i would like to extract exactly 10.025 PDF's. The problem is that my Mac Yosemite is returning the error:

```
-bash: /usr/local/bin/extract: Argument list too long
```

First I thought it would be a ulimit of error, but I increased my limit to 15000 and even then the error occurs. Is there any way to fix this?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you try to *loop* over the list of PDFs and call `extract` for each single one?  This can be slower (because starting the command has to be done again and again) or faster (because the separate commands can be executed in parallel on different processors.

Answer (score 2):

The limit on the command length isn't something you can change easily. I suspect your problem is that you have a shell pattern that expands to too many files, like

```
extract *.pdf
```

One way to manage this is to let `find` expand the pattern and call `extract` multiple times, with as many arguments as possible on each call.

```
find . -prune -name '*.pdf' -exec extract outputfile {} +
```

Comment: Hei chepner, thanks for the faster reply. I have a doubt, i'm using node, so the 'extract' its a node command, and the complete command should be extract 'NAME_OF_OUTPUTFILE' 'PATH_TO_PDFS/*.PDF'. How could i use the find command with mine? Is possible?

Comment: `find . -prune -name '*.pdf' -exec extract NAME_OF_OUTPUTFILE {} +`